# Examples on why not to use divide and conquer

Tags: time-complexity, fibonacci, exponential, divide-and-conquer

I know divide and conquer is a good approach to solve problems with large input size n, but according to Neapolitan's algorithms text book, there are some situations in which we should avoid divide and conquer approach:
"1. An instance of size n is divided into two or more instances each almost of size n.
2.  An instance of size n is divided into almost n instances of size n/c , where c is a constant "[Foundation of algorithms - Neapolitan ].

Besides Fibonacci algorithm, Can anyone please give me an example for each of these situation?

Thank you.

Comment: You're thinking about it backwards. No technique is a good fit for all situations. Why divide and conquer doesn't always help isn't the question you should be asking. The question you should be trying to answer is, "*When* is divide and conquer a useful technique? How can I recognize that it will help me solve the problem I'm working on?"

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure thinking in terms of "divide and conquer" as a technique is that helpful, but assuming it is, there's two situations it's great in: 1. When dividing the data up into groups means you can perform fewer comparisons. A good example here is grouping geometries into grids when you're looking for intersecting pairs. Computing the grids a geometry belongs to is a very fast operation, and it saves a lot of work since you only have to run the full intersection check for pairs within the same grid. 2. When you can parallelize the computation without repeating work.

Comment: @jpmc26 : Thank you but this is the exact same question in the book that I cited. Author says "we should avoid divide and conquer in the following two cases:  1- An instance of size n is divided into two or more instances each almost of size n .    2- An instance of size n is divided into almost n instances of size n/c , where c is a constant" . I know fibonacci can be an example for the first case but I am asking for more examples in which divide and conquer paradigm results an exponential time complexity.

Comment: No, it's not the same question. The book tries to tell you when it *doesn't* help, but you should think instead in terms of the limited circumstances in which is *does* help. They're very different ways of thinking about the problem.

Comment: @jpmc : Ok. Thank you.